# Как задать jquery валидацию кастомному select?

Tags: jquery, validate

Есть кастомный select написанный на jquery, в разметке это выглядит так (у select display:none) при submit формы хочу вывести предупреждение на не выбранное поле:

```
<div class="select-wrapper">
  <div class="styled-dropdown">
    <p>Choose a Group...</p>
    <ul class="styled-dropdown-list" style="display: none;">
     <li id="">Choose a Group...</li>
     <li id="35">text1</li>
     <li id="34">text2</li>
     <li id="36">text3</li>
   </ul>
  </div>

  <select class="activity-group-dropdown conditional-dropdown error" required="required" 
 name="activity[activity_group_id]" id="activity_activity_group_id" style="display: none;" 
 aria-required="true">
   <option value="">Choose a Group...</option>
   <option value="34">text1</option>
   <option value="35">text2</option>
   <option value="36">text3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

валидация на нативном select работает, добавляется класс error (но у select display: none и соответственно визуально ничего не отображается)

```
$('form').validate(
  {
    ignore: [],
    rules:
    {
      name:
      {
        required: true
      }
    }
});
```

как в этом случае вывести валидацию визуально?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Плагин [jQuery Validate](https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/blob/master/changelog.md#190) игнорирует скрытые элементы начиная с версии 1.9.0. Параметр [ignore](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#ignore) по умолчанию установлен в `:hidden`. Вам нужно явно отменить это действие:

```
$('form').validate({
  ignore: []
});
```

Также проверте, что ваша версия 1.9.0 или выше.

Для вывода ошибок также можно использовать функцию `invalidHandler`:

```
$('form').validate({
  ignore: [],
  invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
    if (validator.numberOfInvalids()) {
      for (var i = 0; i < validator.errorList.length; ++i) {
        alert(validator.errorList[i].element.getAttribute('name'));
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: версия плагина v1.15.0 если я отменяю это правило то select не получает класс error

Comment: обратите внимание на `invalidHandler`.

Comment: все отлично но вопрос такой: как мне все это связать с styled-dropdown чтобы подсветить его красным при ошибке (сейчас валидируются все поля в том числе и select)

Comment: Задайте `select`-у и `псевдо-select`-у уникальный для пары аттрибут, например `data-select-id="что-то-там"` и находите друг друга и подсвечивайте.

Comment: В вашей верстке можно даже проще: `$(ваш-селект).siblings('.styled-dropdown')`